# Carry out function for either x state or y state

Tags: solidity, contract-development, state-transition

I've created my own struct:

```
 enum TestState {noWager, wagerMade, wagerAccepted}
```

And my modifier:

```
modifier onlyState(GameState expectedState){
    if(expectedState == currentState){ _;}
    else{throw;}}
```

I'm wanting to allow a function to be carried out if it is either noWager or wagerMade state.

```
 function testWager() onlyState(GameState.noWager || GameState.wagerMade) payable returns(bool){....}
```

I am getting the error:

```
 || not compatible with types enum GameState and enum GameState
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to do it:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

contract Test {
    enum GameState {noWager, wagerMade, wagerAccepted}

    GameState public currentState;

    modifier onlyState(GameState expectedState) {
        if (expectedState != currentState) {
            throw;
        }
        _;
    }

    modifier onlyStates(GameState expectedState1, GameState expectedState2) {
        if (expectedState1 != currentState && expectedState2 != currentState) {
            throw;
        }
        _;
    }

    function testWager() onlyStates(GameState.noWager, GameState.wagerMade) payable returns (bool) {

    }
}
```

And the Browser Solidity screenshot showing the successful compilation:

[image]